# How can I use sed to replace a single character in just one pattern in a file without replacing that character everywhere

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, character, substitution

Let's say I have a file named "optionfile" with the following contents:

```
option-a=0
option-b=1
option-c=0
option-d=1
option-e=1
<eof>
```

I want to change the value in option-c from 0 to 1:

```
sed  -i '/option-c=/s/0/1/' optionfile
```

This works for the above file but it doesn't work if optionfile contains:

```
option-a=0
option-b=1
option-c=
option-d=1
option-e=1
<eof>
```

How can I include the case that option-c gets changed to 1, even if there is
no value after the equals sign, or is some value other than 0 (like 2, or 9)?

Comment: `s/\(option-c=\).*/\11/`

Comment: `/option-c/s/=.*/=1/`

Comment: Thanks to all.  I have to say, though, that stevesliva's suggestion is easier to understand.  I understand that 
s/=.*/=1/ means "match an equals sign plus any character, none or any number of times and substitute that with '=1'.

I'm not so sure what the /\11/ means.

Comment: Just a dumb question:  Why does `/option-c/s/=.*/=1/` work but
 `/option-c=/s/.*/1/` doesn't?

Comment: `.*` matches the entire line... the replacement following the match doesn't get anchored at the end of the match or any such thing.  So in any context in sed, `s/.*/1/` is going to replace the entire pattern space with `1`.  Where 'pattern space' typically means "the entire line" except for more advanced sed.